# Are fractional/continuous central moments useful?

Tags: probability, reference-request

If the $k$th central moment for a continuous probability density function $f(x)$ is is defined by

$$
m_k = \int (x-\mu)^k f(x) dx
$$

We get the variance for $m_2$ and the [unstandardized skew, kurtosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)#Significance_of_the_moments), etc... for $k=3,4,...$ Does it make sense to go from $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and generalize to fractions or real numbers $k\in\mathbb{Q^+}$ or $k\in\mathbb{R^+}$?

To keep this an objective question, I'm looking for an application or use of fractional or continuous moments, either as defined above or in the spirit of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we define the $p$-norm of a random variable $\mathbf X$ as $\|\mathbf X\|_p = \mathbb E[|\mathbf X|^p]^{1/p}$ (this is a function of *basically* the raw $p^{\text{th}}$ moment of $\mathbf X$, ignoring the absolute value), then [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) tells us that $$\mathbb E[\mathbf X \mathbf Y] \le \|\mathbf X\|_p \|\mathbf Y\|_q$$ for any $p, q \in [1,\infty)$ with $\frac1p + \frac1q = 1$. One purpose of this inequality in probability theory is to "uncouple" two random variables $\mathbf X$ and $\mathbf Y$. If they are not independent, but their distributions are easy to understand individually, then the right-hand side of Hölder's inequality may be used as an easier-to-work-with upper bound on the left-hand side.

Now, the natural choice of $p$ and $q$ is to take $p=q=2$, in which case we just get back the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. This treats $\mathbf X$ and $\mathbf Y$ identically. We get more flexibility if we vary $p$ and $q$: maybe the higher moments of $\mathbf X$ are very badly behaved, and not so much for $\mathbf Y$, so we get better upper bounds if $q$ is large. But if we do vary $p$ and $q$, we're stuck taking a fractional moment of at least one of our random variables, possibly both.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

One example: the [stable law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) with $\alpha\in(0,2)$ has no moments of integer order greater than $1$ (for $\alpha\in(0,1]$ even the expectation does not exist). So in order to measure the "dispersion" one should look at the moments of lower order. Say, for $\alpha\in(1,2)$ this would be $E[|\xi-\mu|^p]$ with $p\in(0,\alpha)$.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any reference to how can one use this moments to measure dispersion? (Some meaning, theorem etc) Many thanks.

Comment: @Na'omi, the moments of symmetric stable distribution are proportional to (a power of) its scale parameter, see Samorodnitsky, Taqqu *Stable Non-Gaussian Random Processes*, property 1.2.17.